# Partition Boot Record bootstrap code

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, operating-systems

I've read in many sources that Partition Boot Record/Record is written upon formatting a disk partition and contains machine code for bootstrapping specific OS. My question is how a formatting tool like DOS `format` command can write specific OS bootstrap while it only formats not installs specific OS?

Comment: I don’t quite understand your question. However, one thing: While it is indeed possible to write a boot record when formatting, you can write one any time. The filesystem just has to have reserved space for it.

Comment: I've edited my question so can You now try to answer it?

Answer (score 0):

Look up Georg Pothast bootstrap record. This is 512 Byres 32-bit machine program for running EXE without any OS on PC-BIOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To install DOS 6.22 OS `sys <drive letter>: <drive letter>:` was used.